# Relations between two reciprocal partial derivatives?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

My question is similar to [How to get the partial derivative of the inverse functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145932/how-to-get-the-partial-derivative-of-the-inverse-functions)
 
But they are different.

If we have a function $z=z(x,y)$, we can calculate the partial derivative $\left.\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}\right|_y$. We can solve the original equation to obtain $x=x(z,y)$, and now we can also calculate the derivative $\left.\frac{\partial^2x}{\partial z^2}\right|_y$.

I can directly calculate the relation between the two derivatives by hand. The result is 
$$\left.\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}\right|_y=-\left(\left.\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\right|_y\right)^{-3}\cdot\left.\frac{\partial^2x}{\partial z^2}\right|_y.$$

What about higher-order derivatives? I think this is not a difficult job in MMA, but I cannot catch the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another approach where I give [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative) a definition so that rules are not needed (it happens automatically). I'll use Michael's starting point:

```
eqn = x == f[z[x, y], y]
```

> x == f[z[x, y], y]

and differentiate with respect to `x`:

```
deqn = D[eqn, x];
deqn //InputForm
```

> 1 == Derivative[1, 0][f][z[x, y], y]*Derivative[1, 0][z][x, y]

Solving for `Derivative[1, 0][z][x, y]` (which is $\left. \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right|_y$ in your notation):

```
Derivative[1, 0][z][x, y] == 1 / Derivative[1, 0][f][z[x, y], y]
```

Let's turn this into a definition for [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative):

```
Derivative[1, 0][z][x_, y_] = 1 / Derivative[1, 0][f][z[x, y], y];
Derivative[n_Integer?Positive, 0][z][x_, y_] := D[Derivative[1, 0][z][x, y], {x, n-1}]
```

Your first result can be obtained with:

```
Derivative[2, 0][z][x, y] //TeXForm
```

$-\frac{f^{(2,0)}(z(x,y),y)}{f^{(1,0)}(z(x,y),y)^3}$

or:

```
D[z[x, y], {x, 2}] //TeXForm
```

$-\frac{f^{(2,0)}(z(x,y),y)}{f^{(1,0)}(z(x,y),y)^3}$

Here's a table showing agreement with Michael's results:

```
Grid[
    Table[
        {Derivative[n, 0][Inactive@z][x, y], Derivative[n, 0][z][x, y]},
        {n, 4}
    ],
    Dividers -> All
] //TeXForm
```

$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
 z^{(1,0)}(x,y) & \frac{1}{f^{(1,0)}(z(x,y),y)} \\
\hline
 z^{(2,0)}(x,y) & -\frac{f^{(2,0)}(z(x,y),y)}{f^{(1,0)}(z(x,y),y)^3} \\
\hline
 z^{(3,0)}(x,y) & \frac{3
   f^{(2,0)}(z(x,y),y)^2}{f^{(1,0)}(z(x,y),y)^5}-\frac{f^{(3,0)}(z(x,y),y)}{f^{(1,0)}(z(x,y),y
   )^4} \\
\hline
 z^{(4,0)}(x,y) & -\frac{15 f^{(2,0)}(z(x,y),y)^3}{f^{(1,0)}(z(x,y),y)^7}+\frac{10
   f^{(3,0)}(z(x,y),y)
   f^{(2,0)}(z(x,y),y)}{f^{(1,0)}(z(x,y),y)^6}-\frac{f^{(4,0)}(z(x,y),y)}{f^{(1,0)}(z(x,y),y)^
   5} \\
\hline
\end{array}$

Comment: Thank you! your method is suitable for me.

Answer (score 4):

This iterative method will give substitution rules up to the order equal to the `maxorder`.  It's not a good idea to use `x` for both a variable and a function name, so I called it `f`.  (For instance, if you want to replace the variable `x` by a number, *Mathematica* is also very likely to replace the `x` in the function `x[z, y]` by the number, which makes no sense.  However the code below produces the right formula, if you use `x[z[x, y], y]` instead of `f[z[x, y], y]`.)

```
iter[{eq_, dz_, derivrules_}] := {#, #2, Join[derivrules, First@Solve[##]]} &[
   D[eq, x] /. derivrules, D[dz, x]];
maxorder = 4;
drules = Last@Nest[iter, {x == f[z[x, y], y], z[x, y], {}}, maxorder];

Column[drules, Dividers -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
D[z[x, y], {x, 3}] /. drules
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, @Michael E2! Your method works well.  Because I am not an expert in MMA,  I think  Woll's method is more understandable.  I will choose Woll's answer as the solution.

Comment: @Mark_Phys You're welcome. Carl's method is more elegant (I think), especially since it automatically figures out the derivative whatever the order. I might not use it myself as it is, because it effectively hard codes the derivatives of `z` in terms of `f` for the kernel session. (On a given day, I might have several projects, something I'm developing, say, plus testing my code and other little things for courses I teach and so forth. The lurking definitions of `Derivative` might cause problems unexpectedly.) It can be fixed, but the simpler approach will probably work fine for you